# MySQL error code 1242

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, union

I'm trying to create a view of some columns from 3 different tables. One of the columns 'OrderNumber' is in 2 of the tables so I'm trying to do a UNION for them, but because I've made a subquery it returns an 1242 error and won't return more than 1 row. I just want to know how I can rewrite this query so that there are no subqueries, or is there someway to bypass it. Or perhaps I need to write multiple queries? Though I'd prefer to keep it to the one query, thanks.

```
CREATE VIEW CustOrderItems AS
SELECT CustFirstName,
       CustLastName,
       (SELECT OrderNumber
       FROM Orders
       UNION
       SELECT OrderNumber
       FROM Order_Details)
       OrderDate,
       ShipDate,
       QuantityOrdered * QuotedPrice as ItemTotal
FROM Customers JOIN Orders JOIN Order_Details;
```

Comment: FYI, error code `1242` stands for **Subquery returns more than 1 row**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute whatever your customer id

```
drop view if exists custorders;
create view custorders as
SELECT     c.CustFirstName,
           c.CustLastName,
           o.OrderNumber order_ordernumber,
           od.OrderNumber orderdetails_ordernumber,
           o.OrderDate,
           o.ShipDate,
           od.QuantityOrdered * od.QuotedPrice as ItemTotal
FROM Customers c
JOIN Orders o on c.id = o.cust_id
JOIN Order_Details od on o.ordernumber = od.ordernumber
where c.id = ?
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I am new to this website... I have another problem still related to this topic. The code only works when I don't include 'CREATE VIEW', I am getting an 1052 error, 'Column "OrderNumber" in fieldlist is ambiguous'. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Apologies, ordernumber needs to be aliased.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what are your join criteria because the statement syntax is bad. But I assume you want to join on OrderNumber like SELECT ... FROM Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber. In this case, if you want to use order numbers from two tables just repeat the query and make union of the two like:
    SELECT ,,, FROM Customers INNER JOIN Order_Details ON Customers.OrderNumber = Order_Details.OrderNumber
UNION
    SELECT  FROM Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to clear things up, 'CustFirstName' and CustLastName' are from the Customers table. 'OrderNumber' is from both the Orders and Order_Details tables. 'OrderDate' and 'ShipDate' are from the Orders table. 'QuantityOrdered' and 'QuotedPrice' are from the Order_Details table.